# Check background process from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, background-process, taskmanager

I have a background process running, it can be seen in task Manager while its running. I need to check from my database, whether the process is running or not 
I have tried the following query

```
select * from sys.dm_os_threads
select * FROM sys.dm_os_tasks
```

But it doesnt show me all process running on the system

Comment: Will this help? `SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE
    is_user_process = 1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But this is not what i require.., this gives only process related to SQL Managenent Studio. What I require is, need to see all process as we seen in the task manager.

Comment: It can also be cheked in another way, the background application uses a localhost port. if there is any way from sql to find whether the port is occupied or not, it will also be usefull.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way around. Why are you using SQL Server as the monitoring tool for this other service?

Comment: these views will provide you only information related to mssql threads and process,not for all processes/tasks visible to you under task manager.Upon startup, SQL Server starts threads and then associates workers with those threads. However, external components, such as an extended stored procedure, can start threads under the SQL Server process. SQL Server has no control of these threads. sys.dm_os_threads can provide information about rogue threads that consume resources in the SQL Server process.

Comment: You could use SQLCMD to access cmd from SQL Server but it is quite unsafe to leave enabled,

Answer (score 0):

> I have a background process running, it can be seen in task Manager while its running. I need to check from my database, whether the process is running or not

I hope you are talking about background SQL Server process. Below queries only show information related to SQL Server

All processes running on SQL server can be seen by querying DMV

```
select * from  sys.dm_exec_requests
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions 
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

You can read books online about the documentation about these DMV's

Comment: no, I am not asking about the background SQL server processes. Suppose that, you have kept an Excel documnet open, then in the task manager of windows, you will be able to see the Excel.exe. I need to query from SQL and check , whether any Excel document is kept open currently

Comment: you can consider the background service as an independent ADO application. I am checking this from database, so that i can write it into a log file.

Comment: If you are not looking for SQL Server service why did you posted with SQL Server tag ?. Plus if you want to see more that whatever task manager show you woudl ahve to use Procmon to see what going internally although I am not sure how much it would help you

Answer (score 0):

[use this query](https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/microsoft-sqlserver-background-processes/)

```
select 
                 tblSysProcess.cmd
               , tblSysProcess.physical_io IOUsage
               , tblSysProcess.cpu as CPUusage
               , tblSysProcess.waittype as waitType
               , tblSysProcess.waittime as waitTime
               , tblSysProcess.lastwaittype as lastWaitType
               , tblSysProcess.waitResource as waitResource
               , tblSysProcess.dbid as databaseID
               , case
                     when (dbid > 0) then db_name(dbid) 
                     else ''
                 end as dbName
               , memusage as memUsage
               , status

       from  master.dbo.sysprocesses tblSysProcess

       where 

              (

                  --background process    
                  (tblSysProcess.spid < 50)

              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select db_name(dbid),cmd,spid,status 
from 
    sys.sysprocesses 
        where 
            db_name(dbid) = 'dbname' and status = 'background'
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're not trying to see a SQL server process but another process on the machine for another application, none of the built in DMVs or functions will be able to show you this information natively.  You have a couple of options, one is to write a CLR stored proc or function to check for the process, the other is to use xp_cmdshell to get the tasklist, you can do that like this:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist.exe'
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
RECONFIGURE
```

That will list out all the running processes on the machine, you could shove that data into a table if you like for further analysis if required, or you can play with the tasklist.exe parameters to just look for the process that you are interested in.  Just remember to turn off xp_cmdshell whenever you don't need it as it can be a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

Try This;

```
EXEC sp_who1

EXEC sp_who2

SELECT *
FROM   MASTER..sysprocesses

SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE  is_user_process = 1
```

Comment: @sergio this is also not giving the processess shown in Task manager.

Comment: Imran sysprocesses is no more reocmmended by MS to use. Instead we must use sys.sm_exec_requests