# What are the most important SQL Server 2014 background processes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, process, background-process

I want to know what are the most remarkable SQL Server background processes, their memory usage and what they do. (Note: I have just a single instance)

I've tried different options:

1 - [Check background process from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493122/check-background-process-from-sql-server)

From this question I've tried the following:

`select * from  sys.dm_exec_requests
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions 
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections`

But the most of them don't have "program_name" or "process_name" because they are `NULL` on this fields.

2 - Activity Monitor in Object Explorer (SSMS)

I can filter through `is_user_process = 0` (As said here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1003392-1550-1.aspx)

But I don't see any "priority level" or something that could guide me, of what process is more important than the other.

I want to know at least 5 of these important background processes or services.

Comment: Importance is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Importance is subjective. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services to view what the services do.

Comment: @DanBracuk that's correct. What I meant was like most for a beginner. Like for example, `Lazy writer` or `Checkpoint`. I'm not looking for a deep explanation of what they do, just simply an overall view, like for example the processes named before are related to SQL Server memory's management. From there on, I could do my own research.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien thanks. I meant like `explorer.exe` for Windows. It's necessary to display windows and task bar. The same for SQL Server, for example:  
If you don't 'exec Process1' then you could use SQL Server but without some features, 
but if you don't 'execute Process2' it won't run at all.